# Prioritize or Reserve Dynos to Certain Areas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

I manage a decently large Rails app on Heroku (using Unicorn), and some non-critical admin-side requests are holding up dynos that I'd rather reserve for the customer-facing side.

Is there a way to prioritize or otherwise reserve dynos to specific processes or pages?

I thought about building a new app connected to the same db, only for use with the admin, but this feels kludgy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that functionality is not available on Heroku